# Force iPhone to remember "don't trust" setting when connecting to computer

Tags: ios, charging, settings

Every time I plug my iPhone into one of my computers to charge it, it prompts me to `trust` or `don't trust`. How do I force it to remember he `don't trust` setting? I don't want this specific computer to ever be trusted, and I don't want it to ask me every time.

All searches I've found relate to how to reset the warning dialog in case you've chosen the wrong option by mistake.

It's running iOS 10.3.3